# Execute php script after 24 hours from creation date

Tags: php

I have the following scenario: An user order webhosting package (daily package), but because it's daily package, the service will be expired after 24 hours from creation date. My question is how to execute a php script to terminate the service after 24 hours from creation date? (the script will be implemented later)
Cron jobs are not a solution, because I don't want to execute it every 24 hours from a start date for all users. Start date is when user order the package.
Thank you!

Comment: Just store the creation date and when you access the data,check if the date > 24 hours old ( or select only records < 24 hours old).

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to be executed when user access data. I want it automated

Comment: You must be keeping track of when the package started somewhere and that would include when it started. Why wouldn't a cron job that runs very minute or so and checks the start times not be a viable option? Sounds like exactly what cron was designed for.

Comment: Why is CRON not a solution? It seems to be the best way..

Comment: I know, can be a cron that will run in every minute, but the performance?

Comment: A 10 year old laptop would be able to handle that, let alone modern servers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Linux distribution and the kind of installation (minimal, desktop-centric, etc.) `at` (and `atd` the at job scheduler daemon) is installed by default or not.

To verify it you can issue commands like:

```
$ which at
/usr/bin/at
$ which atd
/usr/bin/atd
$ yum whatprovides atd # to get the package name 
$ yum info pkg-name # to see if it is installed
```

(using a Fedora system here)

If the package is not installed you can install it via your package manager, e.g. something like:

```
$ yum install at
```

You could then use an [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) job:

Below example will schedule `php command.php` to be executed at next 9:00 AM once.

```
$> at 9:00 AM
at> php command.php
at> ^d
job 3 at 2019-11-20 09:00
```